# I'm trying to fill arr in c++ and show it to user. My code is working but, I get error when the program ask me to push any button

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill arr with numbers from -5 to 16 and show it in terminal, but when the task is done and "system("pause");" ask me to push any button to continue(in my language Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . . ) I get error.

It's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[21];
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
            arr[i] = i -5 ;
    }

       const int arrLength = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
    cout <<"length of arr: "<< arrLength << endl;
    cout << "arr containes :"<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= arrLength; i++)
    {
        cout << '[' << i << ']' << ": " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

   system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

I get this err "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted."

And this output:

```
length of arr: 21
arr containes :
[0]: -5
[1]: -4
[2]: -3
[3]: -2
[4]: -1
[5]: 0
[6]: 1
[7]: 2
[8]: 3
[9]: 4
[10]: 5
[11]: 6
[12]: 7
[13]: 8
[14]: 9
[15]: 10
[16]: 11
[17]: 12
[18]: 13
[19]: 14
[20]: 15
[21]: 16
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: If your program crashes, it's not "working" in any normal sense of that word.

Comment: If you look closer at examples looping over `int arr[K];`, you will see that they follow the pattern `for (int i = 0; i < K; ...` or (rarely) `for (int i = 0; i <= K-1;...`, but not `for (int i = 0; i < K + 1;...` or `for (int i = 0; i <= K;...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition

```
int arr[21];
```

defines `arr` as an array of **`21`** integers.

Both of your loops will use `22` elements of that array.

The size used in array declarations is the number of elements in the array, not the top index.

If you want an array of 22 elements, you should specify it as such:

```
int arr[22];
```

But then you need to update the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arrLength; i++)
```

as that will go out of bounds of *all* arrays with `arrLength` elements, as it will use index `arrLength` which is out of bounds (an array of `arrLength` elements have indexes from `0` to `arrLength - 1`).

To fix this loop use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
```

---

As for the problem of filling your array, that can be done very simply with the help of the C++ standard library. More specifically the [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function:

```
int arr[22];
std::iota(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), -5);
```

And if your compiler and standard library is new enough to have [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) then I suggest you use it rather than calculate it yourself.:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < std:size(arr); ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in many programming languages, C/C++ arrays begin with index '0'.

So, when you declare an array as:

```
int a[21]
```

Then, it provides 21 variables to save your data starting from index 0,

```
a[0]
```

to index 20

```
a[20]
```

So, in the following part of your code -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
```

You are trying to access 22 different elements.

```
a[0], a[1] , a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10],
a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17], a[18], a[19], a[20],
a[21]
```

You created an array that can hold 21 elements.

But this 'for loop' assumes a  total of 22 elements.
So, replace your statement :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
```

by following statement :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
```

Best of luck.